# Origin of the interjection "shock horror"!

Tags: phrase-origin, journalism

I am familiar with the phrase *Shock Horror!* which is usually used ironically to announce something that is not, in fact, at all surprising.

I believe it derives from the style of tabloid newspaper headlines and first occurred in the 80s, but I am wondering if there was a specific headline that actually used these words, or whether it is just an invention.

I have searched it, but nothing came up.

Comment: It appears to be from the '70s https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shock-horror%2Cshock+horror&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cshock%20-%20horror%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshock%20-%20horror%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShock%20-%20horror%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cshock%20horror%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshock%20horror%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShock%20horror%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShock%20Horror%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The earliest written instance of this collocation with OP's specific sense that I can find is from 1968:  [*A team of Private Eye drunks recently investigated **the great Mirror shock horror probe**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+great+Mirror+shock+horror+probe%22) The satirical UK magazine Private Eye is certainly the publication I associate most with the usage - in that example they were lampooning the [Sunday] Mirror's supposed tendency to go overboard with their headlines, but at the time you'd never have seen ***Shock Horror*** used together in a real headline.

Answer (score 2):

**shock horror**    It appears the British have authorship of this.  From FumbleFingers:

> The earliest written instance of this collocation with OP's specific
>   sense that I can find is from 1968: A team of Private Eye drunks
>   recently investigated the great Mirror shock horror probe. The
>   satirical UK magazine Private Eye is certainly the publication I
>   associate most with the usage - in that example they were lampooning
>   the [Sunday] Mirror's supposed tendency to go overboard with their
>   headlines, but at the time you'd never have seen Shock Horror used
>   together in a real headline.

And the definition from [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shock-horror):

> ﻿﻿﻿A shock horror story is presented in a way that is intended to
>   cause great shock or anger. "The media is full of shock-horror
>   headlines about under-age crime".
>
> an exclamation You can say shock horror! in reaction to something that
>   other people may find shocking or surprising, to indicate that you do
>   not find it shocking or surprising at all.
>
> [humorous, informal, feelings] I felt intellectually superior
>   despite–shock horror–my lack of qualifications.
>
> shock-horror in British
>
> facetious (esp of newspaper headlines) sensationalistic

And
[image: word usage] showing its definable 'birth' in recent times.